# Encode string into unicode using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, mb-convert-encoding

I'm trying to encode a string into unicode with:

```
$text = 'Hello Â World';
echo mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8");
```

Running that should convert the `Â` character, but it is still displayed when I echo it. Why?

Comment: Well, this setup makes no sense, since the outcome is unpredictable, if you do not refine two things: the encoding of your input string and the encoding of the output environment, be it a browser or a shell.

Comment: @arkascha Can you please post an answer with your suggestion to clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: You see, an "encoded string" is nothing magical, it is nothing but a series of bytes. It is up to the visualizing or processing environment to _interpret_ the string. The series of bytes does not have an encoding by itself.